# Installing 32 bit libraries (glibc) on 64 bit RHEL without using yum

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel

I'm trying to get a 32-bit application to run on 64 bit RHEL 6.1, and the machine does not have access to the internet.  Is there any way to install 32 bit glibc on 64 bit RHEL without using yum, i.e. just using RPM installs?  I grabbed the glibc-*i686.rpm and many of its dependencies from the RHEL 6.1 ISO including nss-softokn-freebl*i686.rpm, but I still can't get it to install without ignoring dependencies (rpm --nodeps).

Answer (score 7):

Mount the install DVD:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/RHEL
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/RHEL
```

Or if you just have the ISO, you can use that instead:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/RHEL
mount -o loop /path/to/RHEL.iso /mnt/RHEL
```

Now make a Yum repository which uses the DVD as a repository:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-dvd.repo
[rhel-dvd]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - DVD
baseurl=file:///mnt/RHEL/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

You should now be able to clean the yum cache, and install the 32-bit C library:

```
yum clean all
yum install glibc.i686
```

You'll see plenty of similar guides telling you to install and run the **createrepo** command but you don't need to do that. The RHEL disc already is a repository, it already has the **/repodata/repomd.xml** file which defines a repository.

However, if you take the RPM files on the RHEL disc and copy them somewhere else and start adding your own packages *then* you need createrepo to build the metadata for the new repository you have created.