# how Install 32-bit packages on 64-bit Linux red hat 6.2 server

Tags: linux, oracle11g, installation, redhat, rpm

My operating system is Red Hat 6.2  server 64bit
I'm trying to install packages for oracle 11 requirement
and can not install i686 packges .

Sample

```
[root@redhat1 Packages]# rpm -ivh nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686.rpm

warning: nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signatu            re, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY

error: Failed dependencies:

        libc.so.6 is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i68            6
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i68            6
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libdl.so.2 is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686
```

OR

```
[root@redhat1 Packages]# rpm -Uvh compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686.rpm

warning: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY

error: Failed dependencies:

        libc.so.6 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
        libm.so.6 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
```

OR

```
[root@redhat1 Packages]# rpm -Uvh glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.i686.rpm


warning: glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:

        libfreebl3.so is needed by glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.i686
        libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) is needed by glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.i686
```

and I can not install i686 Packges on red hat 64 bit.

Comment: ok tnx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should be able to resolve the problem with these two commands:

```
yum clean all
yum install glibc.i686
```

One troubleshooting tip might be to try

```
yum search libc.so.6
```

These links might also help:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156509/an-application-required-libstdc-for-glibcxx-3-4-9-library-on-rhel-5-64bit-syst
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/howto-install-32-bit-libraries-on-64-bit-linux-using-yum-505352/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/289400/rhel-6-x64-running-32-bit-applications

==============================================

ADDENDUM:

You posted this additional information:

```
yum install glibc.i686 Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager Updating certificate-based repositories.
No package glibc.i686 available. Error: Nothing to do
```

This means that none of your currently configured repos happen to have the 32-bit glibc runtime.

If you have the RedHat DVD, try this:

[Installing 32 bit libraries (glibc) on 64 bit RHEL without using yum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435751/installing-32-bit-libraries-glibc-on-64-bit-rhel-without-using-yum)

Comment: [root@redhat1 Packages]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Cleaning repos:
Cleaning up Everything

Comment: [root@redhat1 Packages]# yum install glibc.i686
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package glibc.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do  @paulsm4

Comment: The error message `No package glibc.i686 available` helps - thank you.  You need to find a repo that has the 32-bit glibc runtime, and add it to your /etc/yum.d config.  See my updated above.

Comment: ty @paulsm4  Installing 32 bit libraries (glibc) on 64 bit RHEL without using yum        worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435751/installing-32-bit-libraries-glibc-on-64-bit-rhel-without-using-yum